# Class for Custom Button Event Handling

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

1) I have a Form with some buttons (its in Access, but I guess it applies for Excel as well).

2) I have a custom class that helps me debug that form (and future forms that I may add).

The class simply logs when form events fire, such as loaded, unloaded, dirty, exited.

I'd like that class to have the capability to log when buttons are clicked.

I know this can be done by using a standard module, and loading a public collection there.  Or by directly using the form's events. Or by storing in a collection behind the form.

But I would like, if possible, to encapsulate it *all* in my debugging class. Then its a simple two lines added to the Form_Load event of each new form I add.

My simplified attempt below is only capturing the event for the *last* button that gets added in the class collection, ie. Button3.

**TestButtons (A Form with Button1, Button2, & Button3)**

```
Private Buttons As CButtons

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set Buttons = New CButtons
    Buttons.LoadButtons Me
End Sub
```

**CButtons (Class):**

```
Public WithEvents btn As Access.CommandButton
Private AllButtons As Collection

Const MODE_DEBUG As Boolean = True

Public Sub LoadButtons(ByRef TheForm As Access.Form)

    Dim ctl As Control

    Set AllButtons = New Collection
    For Each ctl In TheForm.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acCommandButton Then
            Set btn = ctl
            btn.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
            AllButtons.Add btn
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub

Private Sub btn_Click()
    If MODE_DEBUG Then debug.print btn.Name & "_Click"
End Sub
```

Wondering if anyone's got any advice, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't handle events from a collection. The easiest solution is to use a separate class to handle the button events, make a collection of those classes in your multiple buttons handler, and pass the button from the class handling the single button to the class handling multiple ones on an event.

Class **CSingleButton**

```
Public buttonsHandler As CButtons
Public WithEvents btn As Access.CommandButton

Private Sub btn_Click()
    buttonsHandler.HandleClick btn
End Sub
```

Class **CButtons**

```
Private ButtonHandlers As Collection

Const MODE_DEBUG As Boolean = True

Public Sub LoadButtons(ByRef TheForm As Access.Form)

    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim btnHandler As CSingleButton
    Set ButtonHandlers = New Collection
    For Each ctl In TheForm.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acCommandButton Then
            Set btnHandler = New CSingleButton
            Set btnHandler.btn = ctl
            Set btnHandler.buttonsHandler = Me
            ctl.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
            ButtonHandlers.Add btnHandler
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub

Public Sub HandleClick(btn As Access.CommandButton)
    If MODE_DEBUG Then debug.print btn.Name & "_Click"
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thank you very much for the advice, and for the helpful revised code @ErikvonAsmuth