# Setting the On Click event to a function without parameters fails on some workstations

Tags: ms-access, vba

In the "On Click" event for a button, rather than creating a sub to run, I have it calling a function as follows: `=sGenerateListQuery()` This works fine on my development machine, but on several other machines, it gives me an error:

"The expression you entered... produced the following error: The expression you entered has a name that {MyProgramName} can't find".

That function is, however a valid function, and if I instead change the "On Click" event to its own sub and call the function from within that sub, it works fine. I also have several other places where I successfully call a function in this way, but they are all using criteria: `=MyFunction("some text")` For some reason they run fine. I am failing to find a common denominator between the computers that are failing. None have reference errors. The ones that are failing are all using Access Runtime 2013.

Comment: Where is your function `sGenerateListQuery` defined?

Comment: @LeeMac It is a public function on the same form as the control.

Comment: I would suspect a MISSING reference on the offending machines. But why not use Code Behind Form when that works? Your current syntax is a left-over from Version 1.1(!)

Comment: You may have already checked this link, but it has a few other suggestions including Module name mismatch and Trusted Locations: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_other-mso_2007/the-expression-you-entered-has-a-function-name/67514f62-4924-40b6-a39f-aa78cbec063d

Comment: @Gustav I could, I suppose, but it was a clean way to set it up, and changing it would mean changing 100+ other fields. The button I mentioned wasn't the only one that was failing.

Comment: Try using a class to handle your control events. You can use tags to apply it to specific fields. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49444091/7296893) for a sample.