# Whats the best event to use access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, events, controls

I have a Form with various tabs and controls on it.
There are textbox controls, and I want to call a sub when any one of certain textboxes are updated. This doesn't apply to all textboxes, and I want to pass the name of the textbox that's been updated as a parameter.

Up until now I've just had to make a `Mytxtbox_AfterUpdate()` event for each one, but this is becoming pretty time consuming and it's effectively duplicating the same code with only tiny variations. I haven't used events very much before; is there a more efficient way I could be doing this in one event that applies to all of them?

Pseudo-code;

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
'I have tried the afterupdate event btw
'but it didn't trigger when I entered new text in the text fields

Dim UpdatedControl as Control
'Need to Find out what that control is somehow

If UpdatedControl.ControlType = acTextbox And UpdatedControl.Name Not like "*excludename*" Then
    Call MySub(UpdatedControl.Name, 1)
End if

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An alternate approach would be a single event handler class (and optionally an event handler manager class), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49444091/7296893)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for events that DO NOT pass values.

so, say before update event, it has this kind of default sub:

```
Private Sub Fax_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

End Sub
```

So, above is no go!

but, the after update event? It looks like this:

```
Private Sub Fax_AfterUpdate()

End Sub
```

So, say I have this form, and I want the after update event for ALL the textboxs to fire.

[image]

Ok, flip into design mode, and click on to highlight ALL of the text boxes that you want the common code event to run for.

[image]

Note the format - you type in =MyFunctionName(), or in this example,
=MyCommonAfter()

And the VBA code? It simply has to be a public function in the forms code module.

It will look like this:

```
Public Function MyCommonAfter()

    Debug.Print "global after"

    Dim MyControl As Control

    Set MyControl = Screen.ActiveControl

    Debug.Print "Control name = " & MyControl.Name

    Debug.Print "Text of control = " & MyControl.Value


End Function
```

And you can pass a value in the function like

```
=(MyCommonAfter("ABC"))
```

So for a common click event, or say after update event of control, then the above allows you to wholesale select the controls, type in the name.

You can of course select each control separate, and then type in the above, but selecting a set of controls and typing in the property sheet thus applies to all controls you selected.

Thus, there is no need to write or create a code stub for each control - you simply enter the function name in the property sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Build a procedure that can be called by each control and design that procedure to take an argument. Still need code in each control's AfterUpdate event to call the common procedure and pass its own name as value for the argument. If all the controls will be on same form then the procedure can be behind that form. If you want controls from multiple forms to use the procedure then put it in a general module.

```
Sub MyProc(varD)
'do something with varD
End Sub

Sub MyControl_AfterUpdate()
MyProc("MyControl")
End Sub
```

Comment: that's what I was doing already, but I was making so many duplicate `afterupdate()` events I wondered if there was a way of doing it using a different event.

Comment: I was thinking about adding the function alternative to my answer but Albert beat me to it and it is an excellent explanation.  Glad you have a working solution.