# DoCmd.CancelEvent / Cancel = True Usage

Tags: vba, ms-access, event-handling

Can either of `DoCmd.CancelEvent` or `Cancel = True` be run with effect from a procedure called by an event procedure whose event can be cancelled?  *E.g.*,

```
Private Sub mCbo_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    DoThis
End Sub

Private Sub DoThis()
    Foo
    { Cancel = True | DoCmd.CancelEvent }
    Bar
End Sub
```

*I.e.*, will the `Cancel = True` / `DoCmd.CancelEvent` statement in `DoThis()` cancel the `mCbo.DblClick` event or is the statement effective only in the event procedure itself?  The former would seem to be in scope in a broad sense, at least, but this isn't clear.

Secondarily, wherever the statement must appear, will subsequent code execute?  *I.e.*, will `DoThis()` execute `Bar` or will the statement effectively operate as `Exit Sub`, immediately ceasing any further execution?

This would seem straightforward but an hour or two Googling around hasn't turned up anything on point.  Many thanks for any constructive thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this by passing the cancel parameter by reference:

```
Private Sub mCbo_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    DoThis Cancel
End Sub

Private Sub DoThis(ByRef Cancel As Integer)
    Foo
    Cancel = True
    Bar
End Sub
```

And, of course, `Bar` is still ran. You could use `Exit Sub` if you want to prevent it from running. The `Cancel` parameter is just an integer that's used *after* all event handlers have ran to determine if the default behaviour should be cancelled. Setting it in a procedure doesn't do anything immediate.

Comment: That's pretty nifty.  I take it, though, that `DoThis()` can't cancel mCbo.DblClick implicitly, *i.e.*, without expressly passing the parameter.

Comment: Nope, if you want implicit event handling, e.g. you have lots of forms and lots of controls you want to handle events for, that can be done through objects and `WithEvents`, though it's rather complicated. Here's a [general example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49444091/7296893) on how to reuse code to manage many controls using `WithEvents`.

Comment: That's exactly the context I'm in; my notation may have given a hint.  The class module is a combo box wrapper that sinks `DblClick` for `mCbo` (the bound combo box) among other things.  `DoThis()` in context is a nav method.  `Cancel = True` ordinarily should surrender focus to the form the procedure opens (but isn't yet; may need an `Exit Sub` or revised choreography).